# Is there a way to place images with different height into 3 columns in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have many images given from a source (from a data base, for example). The number and the sizes of the images are arbitrary. I want to place them on a page into 3 columns like this:

[image]

But I got this as the result:

[image]

My HTML code is (I use a django template):

```
{% for photo in object_list %}
    <div class="photos-item"><img src="{{ photo.upload.url }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

And CSS is:

```
.photos-item {
    float: left;
    padding: 0.3em;
}

.photos-item img {
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Ya need to flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something [like this](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/yqrhw) could help?

It's full of examples in the web; all you have to do is use css3 columns layouts, which won't work in Explorer (obviously)

---

```
<div id="columns">
    {% for photo in object_list %}
      <figure><img src="{{ photo.upload.url }}"></figure>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

CSS

```
#columns {
    column-width: 320px;
    column-gap: 15px;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

div#columns figure {
    background: #fefefe;
    border: 2px solid #fcfcfc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin: 0 2px 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}

div#columns figure img {
    width: 100%; height: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```